# Reading html tables in R using readHTMLTable where most work but some do not

Tags: r

I am trying to read a few hundred html tables using readHTMLTable in R. This works mostly fine, expect for a couple of tables. The tables look fine in firefox.

Specifically, tables are by year and state. The following code reads the first table for Maryland in 2005 and works fine:

```
readHTMLTable("http://www.ssa.gov/policy/docs/statcomps/oasdi_sc/2005/md.html", header=FALSE)[[1]]
```

However, when trying to do this for Maryland and 2006, the table consists only of the first row of numbers.

```
readHTMLTable("http://www.ssa.gov/policy/docs/statcomps/oasdi_sc/2006/md.html", header=FALSE)[[1]]
```

I'm not sure where the problem is and appreciate if anyone could point me toward that.

Stephan

Answer (score 1):

The problem I see is in the second URL "http://www.ssa.gov/policy/docs/statcomps/oasdi_sc/2006/md.html" if you inspect the source code you will see that in the "table 4" there is 2 "tbody". Then I think that `readHTMLTable` read the first tbody it founds in the page. Thats why you only get the "first" row (which is the first `tbody` tag)

You need to precise the tbody you want, in your case it's the 2nd tbody of the table in the div with the id "table4", you can identify this node by `"//div[@id='table4']/table/tbody[2]"`

```
doc <- "http://www.ssa.gov/policy/docs/statcomps/oasdi_sc/2006/md.html"

body <- getNodeSet(htmlParse(doc), "//div[@id='table4']/table/tbody[2]")[[1]]

> readHTMLTable(body)
                V1      V2     V3    V4    V5     V6    V7     V8  V9   V10    V11    V12
1         Allegany  16,515 10,060 1,060   120  1,955   560  2,225  75   460  4,835  7,050
2     Anne Arundel  69,550 47,150 3,245   475  6,380 2,750  7,760 100 1,690 21,900 29,260
3        Baltimore 136,035 91,755 6,040 1,200 13,470 5,545 14,695 175 3,155 41,480 61,215
4          Calvert  10,655  7,035   450    95  1,035   520  1,195  20   305  3,225  4,330
5         Caroline   5,955  3,835   180    70    575   245    835  10   205  1,760  2,355
6          Carroll  24,835 17,205 1,030   160  2,270   825  2,675  30   640  7,635 10,880
7            Cecil  15,030  8,870   630   140  1,415   725  2,435  55   760  4,210  5,330
8          Charles  14,925  9,305   625   135  1,320   950  2,040  20   530  4,275  5,625
9       Dorchester   6,980  4,860   165    65    550   265    895  10   170  2,105  2,875
10       Frederick  28,270 18,950 1,300   225  2,585 1,025  3,205  40   940  8,550 12,080
11         Garrett   6,300  3,760   435    45    780   225    855  40   160  1,910  2,485
12         Harford  34,695 23,020 1,540   235  3,330 1,365  4,140  60 1,005 10,540 14,330
13          Howard  26,855 18,825 1,150   260  2,085 1,275  2,555  25   680  8,595 11,330
14            Kent   5,385  3,865   280    40    485   125    500   5    85  1,815  2,385
15      Montgomery 105,195 76,640 6,085 1,105  8,810 3,105  7,615  80 1,755 35,725 50,710
16 Prince George's  84,190 53,900 2,770 1,025  6,370 5,815 11,420  75 2,815 24,310 32,780
17    Queen Anne's   7,050  5,030   310    50    545   225    695  15   180  2,395  2,825
18      St. Mary's  11,220  7,195   570    95  1,135   520  1,380  10   315  3,540  4,380
19        Somerset   4,625  3,055   155    55    385   180    665  10   120  1,365  1,830
20          Talbot   9,260  6,910   485    70    780   170    695   5   145  3,255  4,105
21      Washington  25,385 16,440 1,245   225  2,500   900  3,290  65   720  7,585 10,595
22        Wicomico  16,040 10,700   490   140  1,300   690  2,205  35   480  4,680  6,480
23       Worcester  13,365 10,235   440    70    965   275  1,130  20   230  4,605  5,765
```